# Find $c$ in equation system with 2 equations and 4 variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

Determine all values of $c$ in the following system $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a+2b+5c+10d=211\\ 
a+b+c+d=52
\end{matrix}\right.$$

a,b,c,d are positive integers.

I've done

$R_1-R_2\Rightarrow b+4c+9d=159\Rightarrow 4c+9d=159-b$

Diofantic equation $4c+9d=1\Rightarrow c=-2,\ d=1 \Rightarrow c=2b-318,\ d=159-b$

$4$ and $9$ has GCD=$1$. $c=2b-318+9n,\ d=159-b-4n$

$a+b+c+d=52\Rightarrow a+b+(2b-318+9n)+(159-b-4n)=52\Rightarrow a+2b+5n-211=0$

I have counted as far as I can. Maybe I did something completely wrong. Do you have any tips on how I can continue, or how I should do?

It feels like all values of $c$ can be up to 50.

Comment: First you should say, whether $a,b,c,d$ are (positive) integers, or rational numbers, or something else. For positive integers, $c=50$ is impossible.

Comment: I don't think there is any restriction on $c$, it can take any value.

Comment: Only if $a,b,c,d$ are positivie integers, then yes.

Comment: Exactly. And this is in fact a very popular homework, where usually *positive* integers are assumed. The OP should clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple procedure for finding a integer lattice basis (given some linear homogeneous diophantine equations) does not seem widely taught. One needs to know how to use matrices.  There is a ton of  material written on basis reduction; it is assumed that we know how to find a basis to begin with...

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&2&5&10 \\
1&1&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1&2&-3&8 \\
1&-1&4&-9 \\
0&0&-1&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
-3&8 \\
4&-9 \\
-1&0 \\
0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2&3 \\
1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2&-1 \\
-1&3 \\
-2&-3 \\
1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The Gram matrix of the initial basis is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
26&-60 \\
-60&146 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

The vectors in the reduced basis are much closer to orthogonal, and the Gram matrix is closer to diagonal. Note that basis reduction for a two dimensional lattice, as here, is easily found (by hand) using Gauss reduction of the quadratic form associated with the Gram matrix, keeping track of the two by two matrix that accomplishes Gauss reduction as $P^TH_1P = H_2$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
10&2 \\
2&20 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

In the lattice given by making the system homogeneous, a reduced basis (as rows)
is
$$  ( 2,-1,-2,1) , \; \; \; ( -1,3,-3,1) \; \; .  \;  $$
Solving the original system gives one solution $( -107, 159, 0, 0) $ so that all integer solutions are found by
$$  (\; \; \; -107 + 2s-t,\; \; \; 159 -s+3t,\; \; \; -2s - 3t, \; \; \;s+t \; \; \;)$$
Then it is just inequalities about $s,t$ to get all four elements non-negative

[image]

Here is is blown up. We can see that there are many lattice points inside or on the black quadrilateral. If $a,b,c,d$ must be positive, we count those strictly inside. If non-negative, we also include any lattice points   on the boundary.

As $c = -2s - 3t,$ we see that  the line at with $2s + 3t = -40 $ (parallel to an edge)  narrowly misses the quadrilateral, so that we know $c \leq 39 .$ A more careful calculation of $c = -2s-3t$ along the boundary shows that positivity of $a,b,c,d$ demands $c \leq 37,$ achieved when $s=40, t = -39$ and $(a,b,c,d) = (12,2,37,1) \; . \; \;$
The nearby (boundary) point $s= 39, t=-39$ in the diagram gives $(a,b,c,d) = (10,3,39,0) \; , \; \;$  which violates strict positivity.

Another nearby (boundary) point $s= 38, t=-38$ in the diagram gives $(a,b,c,d) = (7,7,38,0) \; , \; \;$  which also violates strict positivity.

[image]

[image]